# Can't change theme in Manifest

Tags: android, themes, manifest

Im learning, stuck at simple problem of removing Android's action bar and seting app to full screen. Whole app should be in fullscreen, so I started with Manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen">
    <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

UI stays exactly the same = 
[Stuck at default Look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pntSL.png)
Alright next I tried changing looks in Android studio GUI for activity_main.xml screen. That changes Design preview, but no effect in actual app. Still the same. Is this meant to change app or just design preview btw?

I tried changing in

```
<activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

`:theme` to `@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen` but now app crashes on startup.

I also tried making Custom theme in `styles.xml`, like this

```
<style name="CustomMyTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

But same results. I don't understand why changing theme in manifest  does not work. Is there some conflict in api version? Minimum is set to 15, 26 target and 22 emulator's version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use this code in your activity. Call the function before `setContentView()`.

```
private void setFullScreen() {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        );
    }
```

Comment: Why you are setting the FULLSCREEN flag for two times. And this is used to set the activity as fullscreen from Java code. This can be easily done from manifest only

Comment: Yeah I added just tried `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);` It removes ActionBar alright, but I'd rather do it in manifest, just to learn what's wrong. Thanks anyway, I will set you to answer if noone else helps me with manifest

Answer (score 0):

Use the following theme to set application or any activity as fullscreen

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
```

You can also do it from Javacod. Add this code in your onCreate(); before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried and it doesn't change anything. (Look at first code snippet)

Comment: @Jonzi you are using `Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen`. Try this one `Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen`

Comment: @Jonzi The app crash because you are setting the wrong theme for your app

Comment: Hello, second Theme setting you suggested makes no difference. Still same default look. App only crashes when I apply such theme in Manifest to activity, but when aplied to <application> it doesn't crash, but doesn't do anything also. Might be something wrong with my emulator?

Comment: @Jonzi apply this theme to your activity. it will work. If you just want to remove the action bar use this `android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"`

Comment: Hello, this time it didn't crash for some reason, and it removed Label text but not ActionBar? This is result https://imgur.com/a/DoKIo
Im confused D: Got meeting now, I will come back in few hours. Thanks for help anyway!